# Change the bar colors for Excel bar charts (just one color) for all bar charts in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with 500 charts. When I make changes to the workbook, oftentimes, the charts lose their formatting.

For example, I established a color theme when I first created all of the charts.
There are xlColumnClustered and there are line charts.
The bars in the xlColumnClustered should be green but Excel randomly changes them to blue.

Is there a way to use VBA to select only the xlColumnClustered charts in the sheet and change the color from blue to green?  (Don't want to impact any other chart types.)
Also, want to change the line colors for the line charts from blue to green.

```vb
Sub test()

Worksheets("portfolio_charts").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.ChartType("xlColumnClustered").Select

End Sub
```

This isn't what I need [Change colors of all bar chart categories for all bar charts (VBA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562842/change-colors-of-all-bar-chart-categories-for-all-bar-charts-vba).

Comment: this post looks like it should help  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562842/change-colors-of-all-bar-chart-categories-for-all-bar-charts-vba

Comment: Record a macro while changing a chart - that will give you a reasonable starting point.

Comment: The https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562842/change-colors-of-all-bar-chart-categories-for-all-bar-charts-vba looks to change every chart - I want to make changes to only a subset of charts, i.e., the xlColumnClustered charts only

Comment: What part of the chart do you want coloring?  Its `ChartArea`? Its `PlotArea`? `SeriesCollection`? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over all charts of the worksheet (don't use `Activate` or `Select`). Check the chart type to decide if you want to do something:

```
Sub ChangeAllBarChars()
    Dim co As ChartObject
    For Each co In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("portfolio_charts").ChartObjects
        If co.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered Then
            SetChartColor co.Chart
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

No do your magic for the data series of that chart. The following code sets all bars to green, maybe not what you want - up to you to decide. The color `RGB(0, 192, 0)` is kind of green, make up your mind which exact color you want.
If you set `ForeColor.RGB`, the color will not change, even if the color scheme for the Excel file is changed. If you use `ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor` and `ForeColor.TintAndShade`, the color will change when the color scheme is changed.

```
Sub SetChartColor(ch As Chart)
    Dim ser As Series
    For Each ser In ch.FullSeriesCollection
        ser.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 192, 0)

        ' Use the following when you want to stick to the scheme
        ' ser.Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
        ' ser.Format.Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0.4

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: SetChartColor
Compile error function not defined

Comment: You need to copy both Subs...  and you should put them into a regular module¨

Comment: Thank you!  That is perfect.  If I wanted to then apply a similar change to all of the xlLine charts, I thought i might be able to add another if then block with If co.Chart.ChartType = xlLine Then SetChartColor co.Chart End If but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions on how to do something similar with all line charts in the sheet?

Comment: EXCEL is infuriating!  Now all of the charts have lost their labels!!!  Is there way to add a statement to add labels to the bar charts outside the ends and rotated counterclickwise 90 degrees?

Comment: ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1211").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Orientation = xlUpward
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.Orientation = msoTextOrientationUpward

Comment: can you add code that will add labels to the bar charts and rotate them 90 degrees counter clockwise and place them outside the end of the bars?

Comment: ser.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80) changes line color to green

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my clarification questions, so I will show a way to color ChartArea and PlotArea:

```
Sub ColorChartsChartArea()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, ch As ChartObject
  
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("portfolio_charts")
  For Each ch In sh.ChartObjects
        If ch.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked Then
            ch.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
  Next ch
End Sub
```

Comment: I am tying to color the bars in the bar chart

Comment: @BHF Even if there are more series? All of them?

Comment: all of the bar and line charts on the sheet have only 1 series each

Comment: @BHF I will adapt it easily. I can show you how you can even place custom pictures on the series.. :) Adapted the code.